# Rails App - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am looking to include a simple script in my view (not in a separate file ) I have an inline script in my view as follows ( simplified for question )

```
<script>
  console.log("got here...");  // works fine 
  $(document).ready(function() { // throws error
    console.log("got here...");  // doesnt print 
  });

</script>
```

I am receiving the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Here is where jquery is included in my application.js file

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require highcharts
//= require chartkick
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

This is included in my Gemfile ( above bootstrap , which seemed to be a common cause on other threads )

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: remove `//= require rails-ujs`

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the javascript included in your view? In a new Rails app there should be a view in layouts called application.html.erb, and in there should be something like this:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

This is what will render all those includes into the view, and make them available.